# SQL Server query with logic, outer apply

Tags: sql, sql-server, left-join

I need help with the following query. I am trying to subtract the Deduct amount per acc_No from the amount column. The running amount column should reduce with every amount for that accountNo. After all subtractions are done and if there is any amount left, that should go on the reportAmount column. Report column I need help with and some of the entries in the Running amount column are not matching.

```
DECLARE @table AS TABLE
                  (
                      acc_no INT, 
                      [group] CHAR(1), 
                      DeductAmount FLOAT, 
                      amount FLOAT
                  )

INSERT INTO @table 
VALUES (101, 'A', -100, 0), (101, 'B', -100, 20),
       (101, 'C', -100, 70), (101, 'D', -100, 20),
       (102, 'A', -20, 30), (102, 'B', -20, 0),
       (102, 'C', -20, 5), (102, 'D', -20, 10),
       (103, 'A', -80, 40), (103, 'B', -80,15),
       (103, 'C', -80, 10), (103, 'D', -80, 5),
       (104, 'A', -30, 0), (104, 'B', -30,85),
       (104, 'C', -30, 5), (104, 'D', -30, 10),
       (105, 'A', -15, 7), (105, 'B', -15,25),
       (105, 'C', -15, 5), (105, 'D', -15, 10)

-- SELECT * FROM @table

SELECT 
    t.acc_no, 
    t.[group],
    t.DeductAmount,amount,--t1.LeftFromDeduct, 
    CASE 
       WHEN (t.DeductAmount + t1.LeftFromDeduct) >= 0 
          THEN 0 
          ELSE (t.DeductAmount + t1.LeftFromDeduct) 
    END RunningAmount
FROM
    @table t
OUTER APPLY
    (SELECT  
         SUM([amount]) AS LeftFromDeduct 
     FROM 
         @table t1 
     WHERE 
         t1.acc_no = t.acc_no AND t1.[group] <= t.[group]) t1
```

When I execute it I get the following results:

```
acc_no  group   DeductAmount    amount  RunningAmount
-----------------------------------------------------
101 A   -100    0   -100
101 B   -100    20  -80
101 C   -100    70  -10
101 D   -100    20  0
102 A   -20 30  0
102 B   -20 0   0
102 C   -20 5   0
102 D   -20 10  0
103 A   -80 40  -40
103 B   -80 15  -25
103 C   -80 10  -15
103 D   -80 5   -10
104 A   -30 0   -30
104 B   -30 85  0
104 C   -30 5   0
104 D   -30 10  0
105 A   -15 7   -8
105 B   -15 25  0
105 C   -15 5   0
105 D   -15 10  0
```

My expected result should look something like this, I need help in getting the logic corrected to find the runningAmount and ReportAmount columns.

```
acc_no  group   DeductAmount    amount  RunningAmount   ReportAmount
101 A   -100    0   -100    0
101 B   -100    20  -80 0
101 C   -100    70  -10 0
101 D   -100    20  10  10
102 A   -20 30  0   10
102 B   -20 0   0   0
102 C   -20 5   0   5
102 D   -20 10  0   10
103 A   -80 40  -40 0
103 B   -80 15  -25 0
103 C   -80 10  -15 0
103 D   -80 5   -10 0
104 A   -30 0   -30 0
104 B   -30 85  0   55
104 C   -30 5   0   5
104 D   -30 10  0   10
105 A   -15 7   -8  0
105 B   -15 25  -7  18
105 C   -15 5   0   5
105 D   -15 10  0   10
```

Comment: What is the logic for `reportamount`?

Comment: Report amount is basically. Say I am looking at acct_No 105 that has a Deduct amount of -15. Amount 7 will take -15 from it and Running total will be left with -8, since all 7 is consumed there will be 0 Left for Report Amount, then for group 105, B... since from A -15+7 = -8 is left and it needs 25, we will give -8 to 25 and left over would be 25-8 = 18 will go under report amount. Then for group 105, C.. We have used all -15 between A and B, so nothing to give to C, so all 5 will stay with it and with D also, all 10 will stay with it. Its confusing but hope it makes sense.

Comment: Thanks @Gordon Linoff : Lets check account 101. It has a total of -100 to give away.  Group A doesnt want anything (0) so runningAmount is Zero and report amount is 0. Group B wants 20, so Running amount is -80 and we gave 20 to it, so report amount is Zero. Group C, wants 70, we have 80 to give away, so we are still left with -10 in running amount ,all 70 is given so report amount is Zero.  Group D, wants 20, still -10 is left, we give 10 to it but 10 more is left to make it 20, so we report amount of 10. Hope that makes sense.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Based on your description, you seem to want:

```
select t.*,
       (case when runningamount_tmp > 0 then 0 else runningamount_tmp end) as running_amount,
       (case when runningamount_tmp > 0 then runningamount_tmp else 0 end) as reportamount
from (select t.*,
             (deductamount + sum(amount) over (partition by acc_no order by group)) as runningamount_tmp     
      from @table t
     ) t;
```

Comment: Thanks so much Gordon, I fixed the query a bit like this.  Its close, In running amount column..  account_No 101 and group D value is not matching and 105 group B value is -7 and your query is giving 0 . Several values in Report Amount are not matching. Thank you, thank you so very much for your help.

Comment: select t.*,
       (case when runningamount_tmp > 0 then 0 else runningamount_tmp end) as running_amount,
       (case when runningamount_tmp > 0 then runningamount_tmp else 0 end) as reportamount
from (select t.*,
             (deductamount + sum(amount) over (partition by acc_no order by [group])) as runningamount_tmp     
      from @table t
     ) t;